# how to mock ActionExecutingContext and ActionExecutionDelegate to unit test "OnActionExecutionAsync" method using MOQ framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to mock `ActionExecutingContext` and `ActionExecutionDelegate` for the below method :

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The context and delegate can be created using existing types to avoid a lot of the setup necessary to mock an instance.

For example

```
//Arrange
var controller = new SubjectControllerUnderTest(...);

var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

var actionContext = new ActionContext {
    HttpContext = httpContext,
    RouteData = new RouteData(),
    ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor(),
};
var metadata = new List<IFilterMetadata>();

var context = new ActionExecutingContext(
    actionContext,
    metadata,
    new Dictionary<string, object>(),
    controller); 

ActionExecutionDelegate next = () => {
    var ctx = new ActionExecutedContext (actionContext, metadata, controller);
    return Task.FromResult(ctx);
};

//Act
await controller.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);

//...
```

Comment: I am getting an error that the next variable cannot be void.

Comment: still getting an error, "cannot assign void to an implicitly typed variable"